# UITableview Insert/Delete

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am having one number of section base tableview in that plus button which will add new item in tableview.
While i try add or delete the section from tableview and reload that tableview it will blink old record many times and then add or delete  the section. 
Here is the code.

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SymbolTableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([selectIndexPath containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)indexPath.section]])
    {
        [selectSymbol removeObject:cell.lblsymbol.text];
        [selectIndexPath removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)indexPath.section]];
    }
    else
    {
        NSString *strr = cell.lblsymbol.text;
        [selectSymbol addObject:strr];
        [selectIndexPath addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)indexPath.section]];
    }
     [tblDetail reloadData];
}
```

what is the issue?

Comment: **Never** get information like `cell.lblsymbol.text`  from the view (the table view cell), get it **always** from the model (the data source array)

Comment: how? i don't have an idea.

Comment: You should use `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` or `reloadSections` and `insert/deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` methods. so that it will not reload whole table again and just reload needed part of the table.

Comment: Instead of `cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath` get the appropriate item in the data source array at given index path. Then read the information from the property which sets the `text` property of the label in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Answer (score 0):

You can reload cell which you removed/added
You will not reload all table.
Try the following code please

```
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[ indexPath ] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

or

```
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[ indexPath ] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Comment: it's crash the app

Comment: [self.tableView beginUpdates];
 [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
 [self.tableView endUpdates];

Comment: You need add before [self.tableView beginUpdates]; and then [self.tableView endUpdates];

Comment: @MirMiratom  No, you don't need. That's a common misunderstanding. `begin/endUpdates` is only required for multiple insert/delete/move operations which can interfere with each other. For a single operation it has no effect at all.

Comment: Before deleteRowsAtIndexPath or insertRowsAtIndexPaths you need delete or insert object in array which use in numberOfRowsInSection function

Answer (score 0):

**try following code it may helps you**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  SymbolTableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  if ([selectIndexPath containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)indexPath.section]])
  {
    [tblDetail beginUpdates];
    [selectSymbol removeObject:cell.lblsymbol.text];
    [selectIndexPath removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)indexPath.section]];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [tableView endUpdates];
  }
  else
  {
    NSString *strr = cell.lblsymbol.text;
    [tblDetail beginUpdates];
    [selectSymbol addObject:strr];
    [selectIndexPath addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)indexPath.section]];
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [tableView endUpdates];
  }
}
```

Comment: it's crash while deleteing the row.

Comment: -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], 
2016-07-12 17:08:56.750 DigiTicks[3873:109738] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: Means when you delete or add object from array there must be same number of object and it's problem for adding object or delete object from array.Check your array operation.

Comment: `begin/endUpdates` has no effect in this case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163613/deleting-cell-from-a-tableview-error-code-provided

Answer (score 0):

```
for inserting row in tableview

   - (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
    if (!arrayForTableContent) {
        arrayForTableContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    NSInteger count = [arrayForTableContent count];
    NSString *strTobeAdded = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",count+1];
    [arrayForTableContent insertObject:strTobeAdded atIndex:count];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:count inSection:0];
    [self.tableViewForScreen insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

Comment: call this method where you want to add

Answer (score 0):

I'm not writing all the code nor test it in the debugger, but I will give you an advice of how to proper implement this. Let's say you have a datasource, like this: 
NSMutableArray *data = @[@"First", @"Second", @"Third"];

- Datasource: In numberOfRowsInSection, you return data.count; in cellForRowAtIndexPath, you will configure the cell with the respective index from the array;
- Delegate: In didSelectRowAtIndexPath, remove the object from the data array, say you will need something like this: [data removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)]; then call reloadData on the table view. The table view will smoothly return now just two items.